# iCloud query with NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope fails to update

Tags: ios, cocoa, icloud

I've got a working setup between two apps (one iOS, the other Mac) where they both place files in the ubiquity container and both monitor that container using NSMetadataQuery.  In most cases, the queries update almost immediately after a file is setUbiquitous:YES in the directory.

However, in relation to another nasty iCloud bug which can cause the container to be completely emptied on sync (automatically, not by the app or user), once "the clean setup" between the apps becomes corrupted by said bug the query - on the iPhone side only -  no longer updates.

If I add files to the container on the iPhone, the Mac sees them immediately.  But if I add files on the Mac side, the iPhone never updates.  If I use a timer and the file manager to scan the container, I can confirm that the files are listed in the contents.  It's the query that does not recognize them.

Although I do not think this is a code issue, I will include it here.  I think it is a "iCloud is beta (at best)" issue and I'm wondering if anyone can answer this question: *Since quitting and relaunching the app does correctly cause the query to update, does anyone know how to **force** an NSMetadataQuery to update?*  Deleting it and making another does nothing.

Here's the query code (I tell you it reports correctly to any NSNotification monitors):

```
    self.query = [[[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init] autorelease];
    [query setDelegate:self];
    [query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];
    [query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like[cd] %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, @"*"]];
    [query startQuery];
```

Here's the polling code (I tell you it says there are files in the folder):

```
 - (void)pollUbiquitousStore:(NSTimer *)aUbiquitousStoreMonitor {
     //Query update
     NSArray *topLevelCloudContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[self.fileController.cloudFolderURL.path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] error:nil];
     NSLog(@"known iCloud url: %@ contents: %@", self.fileController.cloudFolderURL, topLevelCloudContents);
```

Here's where I watch the query (I get results EXCEPT once the system has become hosed):

```
    //Refresh
    id queryGatheringObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSMetadataQueryGatheringProgressNotification object:aQuery queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        refresh((NSMetadataQuery *)[note object]);
    }];
    id queryUpdateObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:aQuery queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        refresh((NSMetadataQuery *)[note object]);
    }];
```

Now, you might be saying "you say it's hosed, why not start over?" to which I answer - I can't tell users they need to delete both apps from both devices, turn off iCloud, delete the app from "Documents & Data" in Settings on both computers, redownload both apps, and "this problem will happen again anytime".  I'm trying to build major redundancy into the app.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I might be hitting it or something similar. I'm going on the hunch right now that the background daemon is what is getting tripped up. Did your continued investigation ever suggest the possibility of a timing issue? By that I mean that "after a while" it just starts working again?

Comment: Is this still an issue with Mountain Lion/Mavericks? If so please file a bug with Apple!

Comment: Yes, I came across this issue today in iOS 7.1.1. I use iCloud for my sqlite file's back/restore functionality in the app. Most times, it worked fine but it stop sending notifications on both iPads after I was testing my app with system dates on one of the iPads. Surprisingly it stopped on both devices and didn't work at all even after I deleted app / deleted cloud docs etc but nothing worked. Finally once I reboot one of the device I started receiving query update notifications again. This resolution could be a coincidence but without any code fix it worked again.